# Почему не работает draggable из одной таблицы в другую?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Здравствуйте!
Весь код [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zLrf853d/)

Для `drag` and `drop` использую `jquery ui`

Код который использую

```
//перемещение tr для таблицы
$('.table-media-center tbody').sortable();  

  // tr таблицы, которую хотелось бы перенести вверхную таблицу
  $("#tableUploadMediaDifferent tbody").draggable({
    helper: function() {
    var selected = $('#tableUploadMediaDifferent tr.selectedRow');
    if (selected.length === 0) {
      selected = $(this).addClass('selectedRow');
    }
    var container = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'draggingContainer');
    container.append(selected.clone().removeClass("selectedRow"));
    return container;
    }
  });

 // таблица, куда перемещаем
  $("#tableUploadMedia").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
    //$(this).append(ui.helper.children());
    //$('.selectedRow').remove();
    }
  });
```

но tr с нижней таблицы в верхнюю не переносится

Подскажите, где я допустил ошибку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужен функционал переноса элемента из одного контейнера в другой, почему бы не использовать *jQuery UI Sortable* и его свойство [`connectWith`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-connectWith).

Свойством `connectWith` задаёт селектор другого *sortable*-контейнера, в который можно переносить элементы из текущего.

Представленный в вопросе код нужно переписать следующим образом:

```
$('.table-media-center tbody').sortable();  

$("#tableUploadMediaDifferent tbody").sortable({
  helper: function() {
    var selected = $('#tableUploadMediaDifferent tr.selectedRow');
    if (selected.length === 0) {
      selected = $(this).addClass('selectedRow');
    }
    var container = $('<div/>').attr('id', 'draggingContainer');
    container.append(selected.clone().removeClass("selectedRow"));
    return container;
  },
  connectWith: '.table-media-center tbody'
});
```

И весь код на [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zLrf853d/1/)